# ITK Filter Error: "Inputs do not occupy the same physical space" after affine registration

Tags: itk

I'm attempting to perform diffeomorphic demon registration of two MRI images. The processing pipeline has been this so far:

1. Skull-stripping
2. Anisotropic Diffusion (smoothing)
3. Histogram Matching
4. Affine registration
5. Diffeomorphic Demons Registration

I didn't come up with the process, just fixing and cleaning up a Slicer software tool several researchers have built. I'm a summer student and quite unfamiliar with domain, however I've started to more less understand what's going on. The problem I've been unable to solve for the past several weeks is this error:

```
itk::ExceptionObject (0x1231130)
Location: "void itk::ImageToImageFilter<TInputImage, TOutputImage>::VerifyInputInformation() [with TInputImage = itk::Image<itk::Vector<float, 3u>, 3u>; TOutputImage = itk::Image<itk::Vector<float, 3u>, 3u>]" 
File: /home/parallels/Desktop/Slicer-SuperBuild/ITKv4/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkImageToImageFilter.hxx
Line: 241
Description: itk::ERROR: DiffeomorphicDemonsRegistrationFilter(0x13870b0): Inputs do not occupy the same physical space! 
InputImage Origin: [7.9639916e+01, -1.1042095e+02, -1.0426932e+02], InputImageMovingImage Origin: [-8.8678563e+01, -1.4923204e+02, 1.2193930e+02]
    Tolerance: 1.5000000e-05
InputImage Spacing: [1.5000000e+01, 1.5000000e+01, 1.9199951e+01], InputImageMovingImage Spacing: [1.5154560e+01, 1.5108180e+01, 1.9319538e+01]
    Tolerance: 1.5000000e-05
InputImage Direction: 1.5926319e-08 1.4070701e-08 -1.0000000e+00
9.9237583e-01 -1.2324859e-01 1.4070700e-08
1.2324859e-01 9.9237583e-01 1.5926320e-08
, InputImageMovingImage Direction: -0.0000000e+00 5.5205551e-10 1.0000000e+00
5.5205551e-10 1.0000000e+00 -5.5205553e-10
-1.0000000e+00 5.5205551e-10 0.0000000e+00

    Tolerance: 1.0000000e-06
```

From what I understand, the diffeomorphic registration relies on the two images being coincident, hence the affine registration step beforehand. For some reason though, the affine transformation doesn't line up the two images properly. As a result, they don't occupy the same physical space. I'm clearly missing something but can't seem to figure out what it is.

The affine registration is performed with this [file](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/Examples/RegistrationITKv4/ImageRegistration9.cxx) (I made some edits on my local copy to comply with the Slicer module's way of input/output but they're nearly identical). The transform that was created had the following characteristics:

```
Optimizer stop condition: RegularStepGradientDescentOptimizerv4: Step too small after 33 iterations. Current step (9.76563e-05) is less than minimum step (0.0001).
 Result = 
 Center X      = -1.95155
 Center Y      = 11.6381
 Center Z      = 36.5165
 Translation X = 1.09423
 Translation Y = 0.021133
 Translation Z = -0.0154539
 Iterations    = 34
 Metric value  = 8974.52
 Scale 1         = 1.15384
 Scale 2         = 1.08962
 Angle (degrees) = -5.6116
```

The following code was used to save the transform to a file:

```
  // Write the transform to a file
  itk::TransformFileWriter::Pointer transformWriter = itk::TransformFileWriter::New();

  transformWriter->SetInput( registration->GetOutput()->Get() );
  transformWriter->SetFileName( outputMatrix.c_str() );
  transformWriter->Update();
```

And the demon registration is performed with this [file](https://github.com/BIC-MNI/EZminc/blob/master/diff_demons/DemonsRegistration.cxx) (Made a few edits but mostly the same as well). The affine transform is loaded at line 799.

```
Reading transform from transform input file.
Found: AffineTransform (0x1e0c0b0)
  RTTI typeinfo:   itk::AffineTransform<double, 3u>
  Reference Count: 3
  Modified Time: 1322
  Debug: Off
  Object Name: 
  Observers: 
    none
  Matrix: 
    1.01338 0.0887047 0.0223631 
    -0.11891 1.09423 0.021133 
    -0.0154539 0.0302253 1.14062 
  Offset: [-0.256888, -34.7809, -17.895]
  Center: [-1.95155, 11.6381, 36.5165]
  Translation: [1.56597, -32.6804, -12.3781]
  Inverse: 
    0.977286 -0.0787352 -0.0177019 
    0.105999 0.905809 -0.0188607 
    0.0104321 -0.0250698 0.876975 
  Singular: 0
```

**Edit:** Commenting out the following line does not change anything in the resulting output. ie the initial displacement is not being applied at all. Still don't know why.

```
typedef typename itk::MultiResolutionPDEDeformableRegistration <ImageType, ImageType, DeformationFieldType, PixelType >   MultiResRegistrationFilterType;
typename MultiResRegistrationFilterType::Pointer multires = MultiResRegistrationFilterType::New();

// Commenting out this line doesn't change anything
multires->SetArbitraryInitialDisplacementField ( inputDefField );
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Diffeomorphic Demons Registration` code you are using requires that `Fixed` and `Moving` images have the same physical space, meaning:

- Origin
- Spacing
- Dimensions

Did you try to [resample](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ResampleImageFilter.html) your `moving image` to the `fixed image` space, and then call the `Diffeomorphic Demons Registration` with this `resampled moving image` and `fixed image`?

I didn't know this `EZminc` code but it looks like it requires both inputs to be in the same space somehow.